# Given an image, add white to all surrounding areas within a region - iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage

Given an image G with dimensions `w` x `h`, how can I surround the image with white to produce a new image that is 320 x 480 where G is centered, surrounded by white. The width and height of the incoming image might be larger than 320 or 480, repsecitively, so first I would need to scale it to ensure that it is less than 320x480 (or equal to).

```
-(UIImage *)whiteVersion:(UIImage *)img {

}
```

I would use these steps:

```
Firstly, scale image if needed...then:
1. Create a UIImage of size 320x480
2. Paint the whole thing white
3. Paint G (the image) in the center by using some simple math to find the location
```

However, I can't figure out step 1 or 2.

Comment: I have tried searching to help me with Step 1, but haven't been successful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't draw into images.  You draw into graphics contexts.  There are different kinds of graphics contexts.  An image graphics context lets you take a snapshot of its contents as an image.

```
- (UIImage *)whiteVersion:(UIImage *)myImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(320, 480), YES, myImage.scale);
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill(CGRectInfinite);
    [myImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake((320 - myImage.size.width) / 2, (480 - myImage.size.height) / 2)];
    UIImage *myPaddedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return myPaddedImage;
}
```

You can learn more about drawing on iOS by perusing the [*Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH1-SW1) and the [*Quartz 2D Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066).

Comment: Thank you so much, this works, I think. However, what if the incoming dimensions are larger than 320x480. Basically, I'm having the user select a photo from their album. Could you add code for that?

Comment: I'm sure you can figure out how to do it if you try.

Comment: Why do you think we can debug your code when you don't post it?